# save transfer speed output from rsync to graph it

Tags: rsync

when doing an `rsync -P <source> <destination>` it will output transfer speed during the copy, updating every 1 second I believe.  But it happens on a single line.  How can I save all that text output such that I can plot the transfer speed over time and see what has happened?

*I am troubleshooting and moving a 100gb file over X minutes, for a while it bursts at 400 MB/sec, sometimes will drop down to KB/sec; I want to know what happened over those X minutes of transfer how it behaved... Like in Microsoft Windows the popup window that happens during a copy you can visually see highs and lows of the transfer speed.*

Answer (score 1):

The progress line gets repeated with `^M` (carriage return) characters after updates. So you can convert `^M` to newlines, and if you like, grep out the progress lines:

```
$ rsync -P <source> <destination> | sed 's/\x0d/\x0a/g' | grep %
         32,768   0%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00
    171,311,104  74%  163.34MB/s    0:00:00
    230,258,742 100%  159.33MB/s    0:00:01 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

or something like this, but at this point you can refine according to your needs:
$ rsync -P <source> <destination> | sed 's/\x0d/\x0a/g' | grep %|tail -n +2|awk '{print NR,$3}'
1 163.34MB/s
2 159.33MB/s
```